# probability for each thread group

Tags: jmeter

If I have 3 thread groups in my test plan, how can I set the constant probability (request weights) for each group? 
I'm a novice in JMeter. Could you, please, show your settings on the screenshots?

Comment: Could you post your screenshot?

Comment: Sorry, I've tried to add the screenshot, but I can't:                       

•We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images.

Comment: It is obvious )). For example, the 1st group - 50%, the 2nd - 30%, the 3rd - 20% of the amount of requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well just set the number of threads of each group to a factor of the total threads of your test.
If 100 VUs, set 50 for g1, 30 for g2 and 20 for g3.

To make it dynamic you can use [BeanShell](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) function, you would set Number of Threads to:

```
${__BeanShell(50*${USERS}/100)}
```

And would use a [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) containing:

```
USERS : ${__P(USERS, 10)} // for 10 users by default,
```

USERS can then be passed as a Command line options:

```
-JUSERS=100
```

Sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="2.4" jmeter="2.9-SNAPSHOT.20121216">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <Arguments guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
          <elementProp name="USERS" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">USERS</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__P(USERS, 20)}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.desc">20 is default, to change it on command line -JUSERS=30</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
        </collectionProp>
      </Arguments>
      <hashTree/>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Run50Pct" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">${__BeanShell(50*${USERS}/100)}</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.start_time">1356191395000</longProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1356191395000</longProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <DebugSampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="DebugSampler" testname="DS1" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="displayJMeterProperties">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="displayJMeterVariables">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="displaySystemProperties">false</boolProp>
        </DebugSampler>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Run20Pct" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">${__BeanShell(20*${USERS}/100)}</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.start_time">1356191395000</longProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1356191395000</longProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <DebugSampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="DebugSampler" testname="DS2" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="displayJMeterProperties">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="displayJMeterVariables">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="displaySystemProperties">false</boolProp>
        </DebugSampler>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Run30Pct" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">${__BeanShell(30*${USERS}/100)}</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.start_time">1356191395000</longProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1356191395000</longProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <DebugSampler guiclass="TestBeanGUI" testclass="DebugSampler" testname="DS3" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="displayJMeterProperties">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="displayJMeterVariables">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="displaySystemProperties">false</boolProp>
        </DebugSampler>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
      <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="View Results Tree" enabled="false">
        <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
        <objProp>
          <name>saveConfig</name>
          <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
            <time>true</time>
            <latency>true</latency>
            <timestamp>true</timestamp>
            <success>true</success>
            <label>true</label>
            <code>true</code>
            <message>false</message>
            <threadName>true</threadName>
            <dataType>false</dataType>
            <encoding>false</encoding>
            <assertions>false</assertions>
            <subresults>false</subresults>
            <responseData>false</responseData>
            <samplerData>false</samplerData>
            <xml>false</xml>
            <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
            <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
            <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
            <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
            <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>false</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
            <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
            <bytes>true</bytes>
            <hostname>true</hostname>
            <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
            <sampleCount>true</sampleCount>
          </value>
        </objProp>
        <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
      </ResultCollector>
      <hashTree/>
      <ResultCollector guiclass="StatVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="Aggregate Report" enabled="true">
        <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
        <objProp>
          <name>saveConfig</name>
          <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
            <time>true</time>
            <latency>true</latency>
            <timestamp>true</timestamp>
            <success>true</success>
            <label>true</label>
            <code>true</code>
            <message>false</message>
            <threadName>true</threadName>
            <dataType>false</dataType>
            <encoding>false</encoding>
            <assertions>false</assertions>
            <subresults>false</subresults>
            <responseData>false</responseData>
            <samplerData>false</samplerData>
            <xml>false</xml>
            <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
            <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
            <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
            <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
            <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>false</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
            <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
            <bytes>true</bytes>
            <hostname>true</hostname>
            <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
            <sampleCount>true</sampleCount>
          </value>
        </objProp>
        <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
      </ResultCollector>
      <hashTree/>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Comment: Yes, I know this way and have used it. But I would like to know how I can fix probability for each group and then change only common amount of users, if I need this way.

Comment: Thanks! I've understood that I should open each Thread Group and set probabilities to each of them: for 1st I should write ${__BeanShell(50*${USERS}/100)} for 2nd I should write ${__BeanShell(30*${USERS}/100)} for 3rd I should write ${__BeanShell(20*${USERS}/100)} But why we need use string ${__P(USERS, 10)} ? And where in test plan I can to define USERS's amount? Also in "users default variables"? ${USERS}=1000 (for example) - is it correct?

Comment: Could you explain, please, this moment:
${__P(USERS, 10)}
Why we need this string?
and why we should write "10" as second argument? Can I write another value? How we define this value?

Comment: See http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P , this string enable passing the value on command line , 10 is an example it means if no data passed, default to 10, yes you can write another value. You define it using -JUSERS=100, read http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html

Comment: But if I don't use the command line how should I use this 2nd string? Is it required? I try use 1 and 3 strings (from you 1st comment), but no requests were sended, I see blank sheet in View Results Tree. (If I put amount of users in Thread Groups -> Number of threads(users) manually, then my test plan works).
What I missed?

Comment: I upvote your answers 2 times! But I'm not English-speaker therefore to get information "how to do" concreate goal is more difficult for me from long abstract texts in manuals than from conversation and asking questions or seeing the screenshots with settings for similar work. )) Thanks for your help!

Comment: It works proportionaly when I set Loop Count as number (1, 100 ect.). But I need to increase amount of users evenly and simultaneously for all 3 groups, saving this proportion. And if I set the check-box "forever" for Loop Count this proportion of probability is broken. Could you tell me, please, how can I solve this problem? (If I use Stepping Thread Group there are no possibility for them to set proportion using this way).

Comment: Can you open a new question explaining in more details what you want to do , maybe with an image, currently I don't understand, thank you

Comment: Please, see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039607/how-to-evenly-increase-number-of-users-in-3-thread-groups-saving-proportion-of-r