# Error "Connection reset" in JMeter (SOAP XML web-service)

Tags: jmeter

I have the next test plan in JMeter:

on the screenshot you can see the settings for the 1st ThreadGroup, wich has 50% of common amout of request in test plan (in each Thread Group are 10 different subrequests placed). 
So, +1 request per second is added in average using these settings.

[image]

Then I ran this test and saw this picture (**Error %** column):
[image]

I save errors in file and all these errors have the same text:

```
<sample t="30129" lt="0" ts="1356710138314" s="false" lb="WebService(SOAP) Request 1" rc="000" rm="**Connection reset**" tn="jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group1 3-247" dt="text" by="0"/>
```

Server's cpu screenshot:
[image]

and for database:
[image]

After the errors have appeared my comp started work slowly and slowly (although the errors stopped to appear further)...
And in the same time the server's cpu progressively dropped to 0.

Could you tell me, please,

**What is the reason of this error?**

Have I reached the server timeout? (Because Max is more than 30s in the table).

---

UPD. I have rerun test with next settings: 1000 users per 02:46:40 (+1 Thread Group per 10 second and 10 requests inside each new Thread in the Loop). 
I.e. I have reduced the time of test and total Thread Groups by 2 times, but save intensivity of Thead's adding.

The results are the same (including cpu usage on the server). 
I've received the error «Connection reset» after 990 thread started. There are screenshots:
[image] 
[image]
[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Could you show [Active Threads over time](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime) and [Response Latencies Over time](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/LatenciesOverTime)? (you can just add those listeners and give them JTL that you have, no need to re-run load test)

Comment: How much threads do you have as a total ?

Comment: @PMDUBIK-INGENIERIE I think it's shown in the right upper corner of the first screenshot

Comment: Good point, had not seen it

Comment: Another question, are all the elements on the same machine (DB, Server ), can you tell moreabout it?

Comment: I think you should check response codes of those requests. Code 500 isn't considered an error according to [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54006)

Comment: **@PMD UBIK-INGENIERIE** +1 Thread Group per 10 seconds. In each Thead Group - 10 times runs a Loop.
DB is MySQL5.5, server is Glassfish 3.12

Comment: **@Andrey Botalov**, I have added "Active Threads over time" and "Response Latencies Over time".
How can these graphs help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, WebService(SOAP) Request is not the best way to test Webservices in JMeter, it will be deprecated in upcoming 2.9 version.
HTTP Sampler is the one to choose as it performs much better.

Second, Connection Reset means your server has cut connection. It could be coming from the CPU which seems high but it's not sure.

If what you call "my comp" is the computer hosting JMeter started working slowly then your JMeter instance is overwhelmed by the number of threads (2003 or more?) you've configured. It can come from a lot of factors, read this:

- http://www.dzone.com/links/see_how_to_make_jmeter_run_thousands_of_threads_w.html

Comment: Why don't you link to your site by direct link?

Comment: She updated question. I think Response Latencies Over time looks as it looks as latenices haven't been saved. Is it the reason?